# Combine python asyncio with pyee Event Emitter

Tags: python, python-asyncio, eventemitter, pytest-asyncio

I am trying use the `AsyncIOEventEmitter` from the [pyee library](https://pyee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) without success. For some reason the emitted event "Hi" never reaches the `async_handler` to complete the asyncio future. I also did not find proper examples online. Additionally I tried providing the current event and using a new event loop for the `AsyncIOEventEmitter`, but both yields the same result.

Can someone help me out? Example unit test below:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import pytest
from pyee import AsyncIOEventEmitter

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_setup(event_loop):
    LOG.info("1 - start")
    event_emitter = AsyncIOEventEmitter(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    # Create a new Future object.
    future_result = event_loop.create_future()
    LOG.info("2 - emit event")
    event_emitter.emit("event", "Hi")

    @event_emitter.on("event")
    async def async_handler(message):
        LOG.info(">>> %s", message)
        future_result.set_result(message)
        return future_result

    # Wait until *future_result* has a result and print it.
    LOG.info(await future_result)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok figured it out, the `async_handler` method must be defined earlier in the test...

This worked now:

```
"""Event emitter playground"""
import asyncio
import logging
import pytest
from pyee import AsyncIOEventEmitter

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_setup(event_loop):
    """Receive event from emitter and complete future!"""
    LOG.info("1 - start")
    event_emitter = AsyncIOEventEmitter(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    @event_emitter.on("event")
    def async_handler(message):
        LOG.info(">>> %s", message)
        future_result.set_result(message)

    future_result = event_loop.create_future()
    LOG.info("2 - emit event")
    event_emitter.emit("event", "Hi")

    LOG.info(await future_result)
```